# Scalable layout transition

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, angular-material

How to make such a layout that will make a transition as in [image: this screen] when screen becomes smaller. Is there a solution in bootstrap, flex box, angular material or in any way in primitive css?

Comment: you can do it in bootstrap

Comment: Cool, can you tell me how?

Comment: by using bootstrap grid system.please refer this http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an attempt at what I *think* you want with Angular Material - [CodePen](http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/bZLBXK)

The only way I could think of placing "1" between "2" and "3" for a smaller screen was to create a directive for "1" which is turned on and off depending on screen size.

Markup

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
  <div layout="row">
    <div flex="30" hide-xs layout="column">
      <one class="aDiv"></one>
    </div>
    <div layout="column" flex>
      <div class="aDiv" style="background:pink; height:50px">2</div>
      <div class="aDiv" hide-gt-xs show-xs layout="row" layout-align="center">
        <one flex="50"></one>
      </div>
      <div class="aDiv" style="background:orange; height:700px">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.aDiv {
  margin: 10px
}
```

JS

angular.module('MyApp',['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages'])

```
.controller('AppCtrl', function() {
})

.directive("one", function () {
  return  {
    template: '<div style="background:yellow; height:500px">1</div>'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using flexbox like below.

```css
.wrapperDiv { display: -webkit-flex;
   display: flex;
   -webkit-flex-direction: column; 
   flex-direction: column; }
.first, .second, .third {
  border: 1px solid red;
  flex: 1 100%;
  }
  .first { order: 2; }
    .second { order: 1; }
    .third { order: 3; }
  @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) {
    .first, .second, .third {
      -webkit-flex-direction: row; 
   flex-direction: row;
    }
  .first { order: 1; }
    .second { order: 2; }
    .third { order: 3; }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapperDiv">
<div class="first">
1st div
</div>
<div class="second">
2nd div
</div>
<div class="third">
3rd div
</div>
</div>
```